# Do multiple 301 redirects (in a chain) affect SEO

Tags: seo, redirects, 301-redirect, pagerank, redirect-chain

I have this situation:

1. I had some **uppercase** URLs that I wanted to change with **lowercase** versions.
2. I implemented `301` redirect from **uppercase** to **lowercase**
3. Since my server is running behind **Nginx**, redirection happened with **HTTP**
4. Nginx do `301` redirect from **HTTP** to **HTTPS**

So I have two `301` redirects, one for **uppercase**/**lowercase** issue and one for **HTTP**/**HTTPS** issue. Can this multiple `301` redirects effect the **SEO**? Should I refactor the logic to have only one `301` redirect?

Comment: Related: [SEO: Will Multiple Redirects (301, Permalink Plugin) affect ranking](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/5114/seo-will-multiple-redirects-301-permalink-plugin-affect-ranking)

Answer (score 2):

Short redirect chains might slightly hurt SEO, but probably have no effect. If it is easy for you to change the logic to have a single redirect, then go ahead and do so. If it is difficult, or duplicates logic then I wouldn't bother.

If your site used to be HTTP with uppercase URLs and you have lots of inbound links to those URLs, search engines will have to process two redirects instead of one to pass that link equity through to your site.   Search engines are willing to do that.  They follow redirect chains that are five redirects long with no problems.   There is an old debate as to whether each redirect hop causes a small amount of link equity to get lost.  That debate has never fully been settled, but I now think there is no loss of link juice through redirects.

If you don't have external links that point to HTTP uppercase URLs, there is no reason to worry about whether multiple redirects will hurt SEO because search engines will rarely encounter the redirect chains.

If your site has HSTS enabled, you **shouldn't** redirect directly from the HTTP uppercase URLs to HTTPS lowercase URLs.  HSTS is a configuration setting that has browsers automatically convert HTTP to HTTPS without ever hitting your server.   Some top level domains (like `.dev`) have the setting enabled for every domain name under that TLD.   When HSTS is enabled, HTTP URLs are supposed to redirect to the exact same URL but with HTTPS.

Comment: Yeah the 301 juice debate _has not_ ever really been settled. No matter what John says people don't believe it. You _are (most likely)_ correct tho...I've tested it by simulating models with the PR algo and doing the math. I would have to dumpster dive through a box of old drives to find the data tho, and then pray to Pearson it is significant. I love everything about this answer...spot on.

Comment: Anecdotally (and thus not worthy of an answer but rather this comment), I've had to have multiple 301 redirects on pages before. My traffic dropped 10% for about a week but then returned to normal. @MikeCiffone is right: This has never been settled and probably never will be. There are too many other factors that matter (quality of inbound links, age of domain with the same IP, content quality, Mercury being in retrograde, etc)